# problems converting 'int' to 'string', also with math operators

Tags: c#, string, math, int, operators

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Not.Text =
              (Convert.ToInt32(quiz1per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(quiz1poi.Text)) + 
              (Convert.ToInt32(quiz2per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(quiz2poi.Text)) + 
              (Convert.ToInt32(odev1per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(odev1poi.Text)) +  
              (Convert.ToInt32(odev2per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(odev2poi.Text)) +  
              (Convert.ToInt32(vizeper.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(vizepoi.Text)) +  
              (Convert.ToInt32(finalper.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(finalpoi.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Soon as I got to the last semicolon, I'm having a problem converting int to string.
I just started to C#, I want to learn basic things first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every object in C# has a `ToString()`.  You can just call `ToString()` on your result.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result = 
      (Convert.ToInt32(quiz1per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(quiz1poi.Text)) + 
      (Convert.ToInt32(quiz2per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(quiz2poi.Text)) + 
      (Convert.ToInt32(odev1per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(odev1poi.Text)) +  
      (Convert.ToInt32(odev2per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(odev2poi.Text)) +  
      (Convert.ToInt32(vizeper.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(vizepoi.Text)) +  
      (Convert.ToInt32(finalper.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(finalpoi.Text));
     Not.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

You will also want to use `int.TryParse` as well.  If you type a non-numeric value into a text box `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

you can't assign an int to the text property of a textBox.  Either format the int as a string,

```
   Not.Text =
      (Convert.ToInt32(quiz1per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(quiz1poi.Text)) + 
      (Convert.ToInt32(quiz2per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(quiz2poi.Text)) + 
      (Convert.ToInt32(odev1per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(odev1poi.Text)) +  
      (Convert.ToInt32(odev2per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(odev2poi.Text)) +  
      (Convert.ToInt32(vizeper.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(vizepoi.Text)) +  
      (Convert.ToInt32(finalper.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(finalpoi.Text)).ToString();
```

or cast it to a string

```
   Not.Text =
      (string)(Convert.ToInt32(quiz1per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(quiz1poi.Text)) + 
      (Convert.ToInt32(quiz2per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(quiz2poi.Text)) + 
      (Convert.ToInt32(odev1per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(odev1poi.Text)) +  
      (Convert.ToInt32(odev2per.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(odev2poi.Text)) +  
      (Convert.ToInt32(vizeper.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(vizepoi.Text)) +  
      (Convert.ToInt32(finalper.Text)) * (Convert.ToInt32(finalpoi.Text));
```

Comment: You can't cast an `int` to a `string` in C#.  Your second example won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states, you cannot assign an `int` to a property that's supposed to take a `string`.

You can call the `ToString()` method to convert a number to a `string`.